# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline pass in docker image tag into kubernetes configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline that builds my docker image and pushes it to my docker registry. I am trying to create a release pipeline to pull that image from the registry and deploys it to my staging environment which is a Azure Kubernetes Cluster. This release pipeline works to the point I see deployment, pods, and services in the cluster after it has run. However, I'm struggling to pass in the image that is select from the artifact selection before you run the release pipeline.

Artifact Selection During `Create a new release`:

[image]

`Kubectl` Release Task:

[image]

I cannot seem to pass the image that is selected at the beginning into the configuration.

Comment: Have you tried `_stars.api.web.attainment:0.0.0.14761` ?

Comment: If I put in the full image name with tag then yes it works. However looking to pull the tag in from what ever the user has select when creating the release.

Comment: In that case you need an alias to latest tag

Comment: What if I want to deploy a previous version. Wouldn't using `latest` tag make selecting the version when creating the release redundant.

Comment: @Ross That's why they said **alias**. You tag the container with whatever metadata you need (such as the commit hash or build number) in addition to `latest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the predefined release variable `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.BuildId` to get the version of the selected artifacts. See below:

```
image:_stars.api.web.attainment:$(Release.Artifacts._stars.api.web.attainment.BuildId)
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---general-artifact) for more release variables.